# Is there a point in accepting a surrender in FTL?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

In FTL if I damage an enemy ship there is sometimes an option to accept their surrender. Is there any point in this? I always get more scrap if I either kill their crew or destroy their ship.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The main point is that the fight is over immediately. If your ship is in bad shape, and the enemy still has some weapon systems up, that can be very desirable.

You also tend to get more fuel from accepting a surrender; fuel is frequently destroyed along with the ship.

Lastly, there are a few fights where accepting surrender carries additional benefits. For example, slaver ships will often give you a slave as a new crew member, which can't happen if you blow up the ship. Similarly, there is a quest where your goal is to discourage some pirates; if you blow them up, the quest giver won't give you any additional reward. In these situations, you'll know ahead of time whether the surrender carries these extra benefits, so you don't have to blindly guess.

Comment: @AdamArold Added a sentence to the end, as I realized the answer could be misread slightly.

Comment: i feel like i usually get more scrap from a destroyed ship, and more fuel/missiles/drones from a surrendered ship, i could be wrong about that though

Comment: @Dpeif I'm inclined that way as well but I wasn't sure about missiles and drones. I didn't really look for a source of information on this though. I didn't expect this question to get so much attention.

Comment: @AdamArold slightly off topic but if you play the into the darkness mod it really adds repercussions to decisions such as these, and in my opinion makes the game feel much deeper & alive.